# SQL charge reversal data

Tags: sql

I'm extracting financial information, but ran into charge reversal information. Basically if someone was charged for a service there would be a column with that charge. If the charge was later reversed there would be another row with the exact same data, but with a charge reversal flag on it. I want to only get charges that are were not reversed at all.
Below is an example of what i mean and need. As you can see the RVSLInd column has a 1 if the charge is a reversal. The 0 represents an initial charge

I couldn't do:  select * from from table where rvslInd = 0. because this would get rid of the reversal row only.

```
RvslInd|ExtPriceAmt 
-------| ----------|
   0   |  155.70   |
   0   |  1.50     |
   0   |  239.00   |
   0   |  1111.00  |
   1   | -1111.00  |
   0   |  217.00   |
   0   |  1491.00  |
   1   | -1491.00  |
   0   |  388.00   |
   0   |  72.00    |
```

This is what I want to be able to get back:

```
RvslInd|ExtPriceAmt 
-------| ----------|
   0   |  155.70   |
   0   |  1.50     |
   0   |  239.00   |
   0   |  217.00   |
   0   |  388.00   |
   0   |  72.00    |
```

this would be my new table with a customer column added:

```
CustomerID|RvslInd|ExtPriceAmt 
----------|-------| ----------|
    1     |   0   |  155.70   |
    1     |   0   |  1.50     |
    1     |   0   |  239.00   |
    2     |   0   |  217.00   |
    2     |   0   |  388.00   |
    2     |   0   |  72.00    |
```

Comment: Do you have any other ids in the table?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data, you cannot reliably do what you want.  For the data you have shown, you could do:

```
select ExtPriceAmt
from t
where RvslInd = 0 and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.ExtPriceAmt = - t.ExtPriceAmt and t2.RvslInd = 1);
```

The problem is when the price is repeated.  That gets in the way.

That said, all is not hopeless.  You can get a list of the prices along with the number of non-reversed times:

```
select ExtPriceAmt, 
       sum(case when RvslInd = 0 then 1 when RvslInd = 1 then -1 end) as non_reversed_count
from t
group by ExtPriceAmt
having sum(case when RvslInd = 0 then 1 when RvslInd = 1 then -1 end) > 0;
```

Comment: How would that affect it if the first 5 rows were one customer and the other 5 were a different customer? so i would end up with: 
     customerid|RvslInd|ExtPriceAmt 
     ------------ |------     | ----------|
       1       |  0         |  155.70|
       1       |  0         |  1.50    |
       1       |  0         |  239.00|
       2       |  0         |  217.00|
       2       |  0         |  388.00|
       2       |  0         |  72.00  |

Comment: sorry i added the table above for a better view.